# Positioning tables on a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I would like to create a webpage with several tables of buttons. I need to be able to control the location of each table so that one could be above another, to the side, or above and to the side. I know how to create a table of buttons:

```
<form name="table_buttons">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" name="1-1">
      </td>
      <td><input type="button" name="1-2">
      </td>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" name="1-1">
      </td>
      <td><input type="button" name="2-2">
      </td>
    </td>
  </table>
</form>
```

however I don't know how to arrange multiple of these tables in the way I want. I have attached a picture showing three examples of arrangements I would like to achieve (you can ignore the highlighted squares).

[image: Example arrangements]

Comment: For this kind of grid positioning you can take a look at css grid https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Answer (score 1):

How about to wrap each row with

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

`<div class="row">` element takes several `<form>` element and align them center.

```html
<style>
.row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
</style>


<div class="row">
    <form name="table_buttons">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" name="1-1"></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="1-2"></td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><input type="button" name="1-1"></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="2-2"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form> &nbsp; &nbsp;

    <form name="table_buttons">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" name="1-1"></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="1-2"></td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><input type="button" name="1-1"></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="2-2"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form> &nbsp; &nbsp;      

    <form name="table_buttons">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" name="1-1"></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="1-2"></td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><input type="button" name="1-1"></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="2-2"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>      
</div>

<br/>

<div class="row">
    <form name="table_buttons">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" name="1-1"></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="1-2"></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="1-3"></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="1-4"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" name="2-1"></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="2-2"></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="2-3"></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="2-4"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" name="3-1"></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="3-2"></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="3-3"></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="3-4"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" name="4-1"></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="4-2"></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="4-3"></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="4-4"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form> &nbsp; &nbsp;   

    <form name="table_buttons">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" name="1-1"></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="1-2"></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="1-3"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" name="2-1"></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="2-2"></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="2-3"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" name="3-1"></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="3-2"></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="3-3"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>         
</div>

<br/>

<div class="row">
    <form name="table_buttons">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" name="1-1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" name="2-1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" name="3-1"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>     
</div>
```